# Data frame: Remove rows with certain conditions

Tags: r

```
    A   B   C
1   5   1   3
2   10  2   2
3   15  3   2
4   20  4   2
5   25  5   1
6   30  6   5
```

Hi, I have looked through SO and couldn't find anything that is beginner enough for me. The closest I found was aggregate, but couldn't understand what all the parameter is about, and it seems exaggerated for my usage.

Question: I have the above table, how to I extract this out to be another data frame where A > 10 and C < 5.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
df2 <- df1[with(df1, A >10 & C <5),]
df2
#   A B C
#3 15 3 2
#4 20 4 2
#5 25 5 1
```

Or as @Ben Bolker commented, we can use the `subset` as well

```
df2 <- subset(df1, A > 10 & C <5)
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(A = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L), B = 1:6,
C = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: less elegantly but perhaps more understandably `df1[df1$A>10 & df1$C<5,]`; or `subset(df1,A>10 & C<5)`

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, I used `with` in case if the OP wants to add other conditions into it.

Comment: Hey there. Thank! :) For some reason, my data returns as "data frame with 0 columns and <some number> rows. Out of topic, but any idea?

Comment: @Farid I updated the post with the data.  Is it based on the same example?

Comment: @Farid Can you update your post with the dput  output of the example.  i.e. `dput(yourdata)`. or the `str(yourdata)`.  I guess the class of the columns may not be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for those who are familiar with MySQL would be to use the package **sqldf**

```
require(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT *
   FROM df
   WHERE A > 10 and C < 5')
```

The output for this would be:

```
     A   B   C
1   15   3   2
2   20   4   2
3   25   5   1
```

Comment: While sqldf does work with MySQL the default, which is what is used in the answer, is to use SQLite.